# How to decode latin1_swedish_ci to utf8_general_ci in tastypie?

Tags: python, mysql, django, utf-8, tastypie

I am using database create by Xtreamedia source code and database most of field char  has Collation is latin1_swedish_ci but really don't know how it decode and work well in php they using header utf-8.

By the way I am building an API using **django tastypie** from this db and I want to keep the database structure and have problem to decode to utf-8 when generate response to client. I already write a CustomSerializer.

```
import json

from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
from tastypie.serializers import Serializer


class CustomJSONSerializer(Serializer):
    def to_json(self, data, options=None):
        options = options or {}

        data = self.to_simple(data, options)
        if data.get('objects'):
            res = []
            for i in data['objects']:
                if i.get('name_vn'):
                    k = i
                    try:
                        k['name_vn'] = i['name_vn'].encode('utf8').decode('latin1', errors='ignore')
                    except:
                        print i
                    res.append(k)
            data['object'] = res
        return json.dumps(data, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder, sort_keys=True)
```

But it doesn't work well some decoded but some doesn't

Is that any trick here in mysql connector? Because when I convert field like http://www.bothernomore.com/2008/12/16/character-encoding-hell/ and it works well.

```
ALTER TABLE `name` MODIFY COLUMN `title` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET binary;
ALTER TABLE `name` MODIFY COLUMN `title` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

I think is the way to convert to utf-8 the problem is how to implement in Python?